# Interaction from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have used bottom navigation view in my activity. 5 items are present in bottom navigation view. on click of each item, a fragment is opened in the container of activity. Now I want call method of fragment via activity.
Is it ok to call fragment's method directly from activity?
I am currently using following way:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isAdded() && fragment.isVisible())
            fragment.method("calling from activity");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the things a bit.Actually fragment is a part of activity and is managed by activity. You just need to handle a fragment call in your activity that's it.
Then you can easily and separately manage your methods for each fragment.
I hope it will help. Happy Coding.

Comment: I am making a network query in activity using retofit. When I get json response, I want to update data in 2 fragments of the activity. I want to know is it ok to directly call method present in two fragments from activity to update data?

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace your FRAME Layout with your Fragment..

Every Time when you click on Bottom Navigation icon replace Frame layout with Fragment

we have lot of examples .. one of those. it may be helpful

> [Bottom Navigation](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/bottom-navigation-android-example/)